# How to declare a list with different classes that all have the same function?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently learning c++ and got stuck on the following problem:

I have unknown number of different classes that all have the same function:

```
class A {
    doStuff();
}
class B {
    doStuff();
}
class C {
    doStuff();
}
```

There is a function that creates a single one of these classes with the help of templates:

```
template<class T>
auto createClass(T classToCreate) {
    return make_shared<classToCreate>();
}
```

And I have a second function that's supposed to start the function "doStuff" within every object.

Is there a way to create a list or something else that I can iterate through so that I can keep the process dynamic?

I'm not sure what I have to search for to find a solution.

Comment: `std::variant`?

Comment: `std::any` if the object set is unbounded.

Comment: Alternatively to `std::variant`, this is exactly what `virtual` functions in a base class are for and if you are using dynamic allocation already anyway, then that might be what you are looking for. Which of the two tools is the correct one depends on your requirements.

Comment: @NathanOliver You can't call a member function on an object contained in a `std::any` without again individually checking against each element of the bounded type set. The only thing it is good for is copying an unknown type.

Comment: *"within every object"* -- but the function created only a **single** object. How do you go from this function to multiple objects?

Comment: What is the specific topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook that you're "currently learning c++" from, where this practice problem comes from? There are several possible approaches for doing things of this sort in C++, need to know more exactly what specific C++ concept this practice problem is meant to reinforce, and teach, in order to point you in the right direction.

Comment: *I'm currently learning c++ and got stuck on the following problem:*  Where are you learning C++ from?  Where is this problem from?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik and at Eljay,

this problem comes from no textbook or youtube tutorial. It's learning by doing and simply one of my first c++ projects and the first time I worked with templates, so there is no place I could lead you to.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated and the hardest to learn general purpose programming language in use today. C++'s formal specifications are approximately two thousand pages long. Attempting to learn C++ organically is just not realistic. It will take a very long time asking one question at a time, about C++, to cover all of those two thousand pages. The only realistic way to learn C++ is by following an organized, textbook-guided study course that introduces each concept, in a meaningful order, starting with introductory topics and progressing to each more complicated topic, in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears a useful place for an abstract (pure virtual) base class. It defines an interface the derived class must implement, but not any of the implementation details.

```
class I {
public:
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

class A : public I {
public:
    void doStuff() override {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }
};

class B : public I {
public:
    void doStuff() override {
        std::cout << "Class B\n";
    }
};

class C : public I {
    int x;
public:
    C(int x) : x(x) { }
 
    void doStuff() override {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
};
```

You can now ensure that the object received by a function implements this functionality.

```
void foo(I *obj) {
    if (obj) obj->doStuff();
}
```